# eclipse.exe -clean.cmdを動かしたところキャッシュのクリーンアップが終わらずアプリケーションエラーが出る。

Tags: eclipse

eclipse.exeが急に起動しなくなり、とりあえずeclipse.exe -clean.cmdを動かしてみました。
するとキャッシュのクリーンアップがなかなか終わらず、しばらく放置すると以下のようなエラーが出ました。
16:39:03.528～17:23:58.822と、かなり時間がかかっているようです。
このエラーの後eclipse.exeを動かすと、「キャッシュのクリーンアップ中…この処理は数分かかる場合があります。しばらくお待ちください。」と出たまま動きません。
どなたか解決できる方はいらっしゃいませんか？

追記　とりあえず、もう一度eclipseを入れ直してみると動きました。結局原因は不明なので、一応エラーの起きるバージョンも残してあります。何かあればコメント頂けると嬉しいです。

````
!SESSION 2023-01-10 16:39:03.528 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.25.0.I20220831-1800
java.version=17.0.4.1
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ja_JP
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-01-10 17:23:58.822
!MESSAGE アプリケーション・エラー
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -2147483647 > 1
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3782)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3742)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.lambda$6(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:391)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createUniqueWorkspaceNameMap(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:788)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.showChooseWorkspaceDialog(IDEApplication.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467) ```
````